# Suspended Transaction Receipt Printing Dynamics AX POS

Tags: transactions, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to reprint a suspended receipt that is stored in database with all its belongings and data.

Now I need to fetch this transaction in an object of PosTransaction class.
I have tried following code but it returned some other undesired transaction.

```
posTransaction = (PosTransaction)BlankOperations.SApplication.BusinessLogic.SuspendRetrieveSystem.RetrieveTransaction(transactionId);
```

Is there any solution to fetch suspended transaction in PosTransaction Object?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I want to print a suspended transaction for which I need to fetch the transaction from database in the form of PosTrasaction Object. I am using the code shown in the question. but this is causing some effects other than just returning the PosTransaction Ojbect. I want another solution to get the postransactio  object in order to print the suspended transaction. is there any other solution you know ???

Comment: thanx for the reply by the way. I am looking forward for more.

Comment: It is outside my domain, sorry.